# npm locally installed dependency not being loaded from node_modules

Tags: typescript, npm, angular, systemjs

I a npm module 'sampleApp' which depends on my another npm module called 'mycommon'.

I createa a tar ball for "mycommon" module using npm pack command and installed it in "sampleApp" using
"npm install ../../mycommon-1.0.0.tar.gz". Verified that node_modules for samlpleApp now contains the mycommon folder and its subdirectories correctly.

Now when i launch the sampleApp, "mycommon/mycomponent/comp.js" fails to load. 
My other angular2 imports are being loaded from "node_modules" correctly however locally installed dependency "mycommon" is not being loaded from node_modules. Browser network log shows that its trying to load it from file-cache.

Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks
Prasad

Comment: have you check if you have a local `.npmrc` file overwriting your default configuration for save modules on `node_modules`?? check if you have that file with a property called prefix changed.

Comment: Are you using systemjs? Did you added the mapping to config.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, .ts files were compiled into a separate outDir=dist.
When i bundled the module using npm pack it was bundling the dist folder and the contents / directories at my module root.

SO i put a components.js / components.d.ts file in the module root directory re-exporting the APIs in dist folder.  So consuming application would import the APIs form exported file "mycommand/components".